# Show Custom Values in Combo box

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Here Is the story :

I have this code which gets col names of my table and fill the combo box

```
        void fillcombo()
    {


        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        string com = "SELECT * FROM driver";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(com, con);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            cmbfilter.Items.Add(reader.GetName(i));
        }
```

then from it i execute this Query

```
"SELECT driverFName,driverLName,vehicleID,driverContact FROM driver WHERE "+cmbfilter.SelectedText+" LIKE '" + seachtext + "%';";
```

this thing work like a charm but the combo box values are not so neat.

[image]

instead of that if i can give it some custom values

such as

driverFName =  First Name
driverLName = Last Name

likewise

is there any way to do so..

this is only for testing please don't worry about not using parameter  values

Comment: i have add alias and now combo box is OK but the search query giving me errors it gets the alias name not the real column name after WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution it works but not sure if it is the correct way

used a swich Case

```
 void fillcombo()
    {


        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        string com = "SELECT driverFName,driverLName,vehicleID,driverDlNo,driverContact FROM driver";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(com, con);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        cmbfilter.DisplayMember = "Text";
        cmbfilter.ValueMember = "Value";
        List<ComboboxItem> list = new List<ComboboxItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {

            string C = reader.GetName(i);
            string _name="";
            string _value = "";
            switch (C)
            {
                  case "id":
                    _name= "ID";
                    _value = C;
                        break;



                  case "driverFName":
                        _name = "First Name";
                        _value = C;
                        break;

                  case "driverLName":
                        _name = "Last name";
                        _value = C;
                        break;

                  case "vehicleID":
                        _name = "Vehicle No";
                        _value = C;
                        break;

                  case "driverDlNo":
                        _name = "Licence No";
                        _value = C;
                        break;

                  case "driverContact":
                        _name = "Contact No";
                        _value = C;

                        break;


            }
```

then this code to create the combo box with the values

```
                ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = _name;
            item.Value = _value;
            list.Add(item);



        }
        cmbfilter.DataSource = list;
        cmbfilter.SelectedItem = null;
        }



    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting [alias](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) on your query?

```
"SELECT 
driverFName as 'First Name',
driverLName as 'Last Name',
vehicleID,driverContact FROM driver WHERE "+cmbfilter.SelectedText+" LIKE '" + seachtext + "%';";
```

Comment: can you be more specific pls ?

Comment: What kind of "specific" do you want? You already use alias in based on your comment, it worked but I don't understand what error are you saying on your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can go with DB aliases OR you could do a matching dictionary that uses column names as keys and their matching User-friendly values.

Or you can also go with resources file based on the same mechanism, good for localization.

Your call.

**EDIT: As requested, more details.**

*Aliases*

Use `driverFName AS "New Column Name"` but it will add unnecessary weight to your SQL request.

*Dictionary*

Create a simple dictionary `<String, String>` in your class, with the column name as the **Key** and the user friendly **Value**. Better but still, localization is going to be true hell.

So you'll be able to do something like `var niceName = stringDictionary["driverFName"]`.

*Resources*

Last solution, use **Resource files** in your project, set it up for the different locales you'll be supporting. Each file is like a **Dictionary**, to you'll rely on the same system than the second solution but with a more robust solution on the long run.

Comment: can you be more specifc ? its nice if can give a sample or steps :)